# When to use IEqualityComparer in an app targeting .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, iequalitycomparer

Is there any benefit for me to implement the weakly typed [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.aspx) in .NET 4.0 apps in addition to the [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) interface?

Another angle is I can always implement `IEqualityComparer<System.Object>` to make up an equally weakly typed scenario and never need to resort to `IEqualityComparer` for new code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just derive from [`EqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx) then you don't have to worry about it because it implements both `IEqualityComparer` and `IEqualityComparer<T>`. So you get weak typing for free when you implement strong typing.

That said, it's reasonably unlikely that you'll find yourself needing the weakly-typed version. Only a handful of BCL classes use it, and they're not common ones.